# Why is there an option to disable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Question out of curiosity, why would there be an option to disable Javascript in web browsers when it is one of the basic things for a website to function properly?

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons:

- **Security**: You have no idea what a website actually does on your computer. For instance, Javascript is widely used to track users, generate profiles and collect their browsing habits for marketing/advertising purposes. Some users/companies don't want that.
- **Performance**: Slow devices (i.e. embedded computers, mobile phone) can struggle executing complex scripts.
- **Accessibility**: Handicapped users, i.e. blind people might use special devices that can read plain html, but not Javascript.

That said a really good website should be fully usable without Javascript. It's always good to have a fall back plain html version for the few users who for whatever reason can't or don't want to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is only a security option but you are right, disabling Javascript makes today no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are doing in javascript you can access local files on a users machine, companies used to disable javascript and activeX all the time, now a days, it is not the norm.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you are in a protected webpage and you try to copy a text, right-click is disabled, so, if you are able to disable javascript you can disable functions like this.

Firefox plugins like NoScript makes you able to disable scripting and individual scripts in certain web pages. And it is widely used.